# Formatar coluna CPF com expressão regular

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle10g, sqlfiddle

Em uma tabela contendo a coluna **CPF** gostaria de formatá-la de modo a apresentar o conteúdo de forma adequada. Por forma adequada me refiro ao formato **999.999.999-99**. É possível formatar este conteúdo por meio de expressão regular?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[SQLFiddle para o teste](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e98e4/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você quer é possível utilizando a função [`regexp_replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(cpf,
        '([[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{2})',
        '\1.\2.\3-\4') AS cpf_formatado
FROM cadastro;
```

A expressão regular vai dividir os dígitos em 3 grupos de 3 e o final em um grupo de 2. Por fim esses grupos são reordenados com as divisões `'\1.\2.\3-\4'`.

Exemplo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e98e4/15).

Answer (score 0):

Não é uma boa prática em banco de dados armazenar os dados já formatados. Cabe ao programador formatar os dados da melhor forma na hora de exibir na interface, a função do banco é apenas fornecer esses dados, de modo cru.

Comment: Não quero armazenar os dados. Quero recuperar os dados e em cima da coluna CPF aplicar uma formatação.